# Angularjs Ui-scrollpoint issue

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui-scrollpoint,'ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize']);
```

Im working with angularjs .I want to use scrollpoint in my angularjs application .But always im getting error and my module doesnot get loaded.What is the issue with this. Can anyone help me giving the required cdn for `ui-scrollpoint`?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/PDK6rlZF8kPLk1Rhgt0z?p=preview i referred the this plunker and im using this scrollpoint.js file inside my project

Answer (score 0):

You can take it directly from the GitHub, where it's repository is hosted:

https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-scrollpoint/master/dist/scrollpoint.js

Also, https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/angular-ui-scrollpoint@2.1.1/dist/scrollpoint.min.js